# Sort all the elements of the list according to the first letter, irrespective of their cases . Do not use any inbuilt sorting function

Tags: python, list

I am trying to sort the below languages list but not getting the desired output. Not sure why this is happening. I am new to the python programming.

```
languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++']
Output: ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'python', 'R', 'scala']

languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++']
for i in range(0, len(languages)):
    if i != len(languages)-1:
        if languages[i][0].lower() < languages[i+1][0].lower():
            print(languages[i], languages[i+1] )
            print(languages)
        else:
            temp1 = languages[i]
            temp2 = languages[i+1]
            languages[i] = temp2
            languages[i+1] = temp1
            print(languages)
    else:
        languages.insert(0, languages[i])
        
languages
```

Comment: could you tell use what you are doing? How does your algorithm work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) on first letter:

```
languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++'] 
for i in range(len(languages)-1):
    for j in range(0, len(languages)-i-1):
        if (languages[j][0]).lower() > (languages[j+1][0]).lower():
            languages[j+1],languages[j] = languages[j],languages[j+1]

print(languages)
>> ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'R', 'python', 'scala']
```

Comment: I tried the languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++']
for i in range(len(languages)-1):
    if languages[i+1][0] < languages[i][0]:
        languages[i+1],languages[i] = languages[i],languages[i+1]
languages
But the output is ['R', 'Java', 'python', 'C', 'C++', 'scala']

Comment: My input will be  languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++']
and output will be  Output: ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'python', 'R', 'scala']

Comment: Edited. Now check it out.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

A less performant solution (takes out the first element at each iteration)

```py
languages = ['python', 'R', 'Java', 'scala', 'C', 'C++']

def first_comes_first(string1, string2):
    first_first = True
    # Make the shorter string `string1`
    if len(string2) < len(string1):
        string1, string2 = string2, string1
        first_first = False

    for i, _ in enumerate(string1):
        if string1[i].lower() > string2[i].lower():
            return not first_first
        else:
            return first_first


ordered = []
while len(languages) > 0:
    lang1 = languages[0]

    temp_languages = languages[1:].copy()
    for lang2 in temp_languages:
        if not first_comes_first(lang1, lang2):
            lang1 = lang2
     
    ordered.append(lang1)
    languages.remove(lang1)

ordered
# Output: ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'python', 'R', 'scala']
```